# Origin of the Boolean Model of Information Retrieval

Tags: information-retrieval, definitions, history

Simple question, but I can't really find the answer to that: Who "invented" Boolean Retrieval? Of course, I assume that the concept grew over time, but is there a paper or publication that mentions/defines the Boolean Model as a whole for the first time?

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_model_of_information_retrieval), the book by Lancaster and Fayen (1973) is cited, but I couldn't find any definition in there, either.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for "Boolean Retrieval" in [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Boolean%20Retrieval%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=&as_yhi=1973) with upper date limit finds two papers that seems related from the sixties.

https://heinonline.org/HOL/LandingPage?handle=hein.journals/juraba8&div=16&id=&page=

https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0673362.pdf

There is a [reference](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0413620.pdf) to Non-Boolean retrieval from 1963, hinting that the term was known before.
Try checking the references in these papers.